# vue js slots is not appearing data for template layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs-slots

I am using slots first time in vue.js for layout. as per reference I included the component and used the slot tag in the proper place where I needed it, but still, the slot tag is not able to render my tags or data I want to display on my layout page. I found no error in the console log, my header component, and footer components are included successfully, and appearing on the web page. but the slot tag is not working.
Here is my code. please help me to find my mistake.

SlotTest.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <test-component>
      <h1>Testing Slots</h1>
    </test-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from "./Test";
export default {
  components: { TestComponent },
};
</script>
```

Test.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header-content> </header-content>
    <slot> </slot>
    <footer-content> </footer-content>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import HeaderContent from "./Header";
import FooterContent from "./Footer";
export default {
  components: { HeaderContent, FooterContent },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of Vue?

Comment: The way you use slots should work (with Vue 2.6 at least). Are there any build errors, any errors seen in Developer Console (F12)?

Comment: No build errors

Comment: did you tried using named slot ?

Comment: Yes Anupam singh i also tried it with name slot, but did not work.

Comment: My vue version is  vue@2.6.12, and my npm version is 6.14.6.

Comment: There are no reason for your slot not rendering... i even try your code on my VS Code and all running with no errors and everything is ok! If you are not applying CSS and has no errors, try to delete, or comment, the headerContent and footerContent from Test.Vue and check if the slot is rendered.

Comment: @JS_LnMstr I tried, but sitll page is blank.

Comment: try this: close your 'npm run' on terminal, clear cache with the command 'npm cache clean --force'  and run 'npm run serve' again.

Comment: There's nothing in your post to suggest why this isn't working. You need to do some debugging and update your question.

Comment: @JS_LnMstr i tried with you mentioned above, but still failed.

Comment: Well sir.. like @Daniel_Knights said your code ir crystal clear and theres nothing wrong with that!

Comment: @Daniel_Knights please help me to fine my mistake in code.

Comment: Can you check the devtools to see if it exists in the HTML? There's a chance it is working but there's a CSS issue causing it to be invisible.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Alright sir